# Reactive Extensions for processing continuous streams of messages

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a message processing application that currently operates on small messages that fit easily into memory. I am extending it to operate on messages larger than memory (in the 10s to 100s of gigabytes) which will require some kind of streaming approach. I like what I've seen so far with how Reactive Extensions (especially [this piece on "Rx on the server"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffva/archive/2010/07/23/rx-on-the-server-part-1-of-n-asynchronous-system-io-stream-reading.aspx)) model an asynchronous push event stream and how Rx can interoperate with other constructs and patterns in C# such as `System.IO.Stream` (see previous link), [TPL Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211785(v=vs.103).aspx), the [APM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromasyncpattern(v=vs.103).aspx), and the [EAP pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromeventpattern(v=vs.103).aspx).

E.g., something such as `IObservable<MyMessage>` is a plain vanilla example of an Rx stream. Because my app's implementation of `MyMessage` represents data too large to fit into memory, I need something along the lines of `IObservable<MyMessageChunk>` in which a variable number of `MyMessageChunk` instances combine to represent a single `MyMessage`. I need something like this paint-tastic marble diagram:

[image: Rx "marble" diagram]

In the above diagram, each circle represents a chunk of a message and the colors delineate breaks between messages. The red X represents an error in the processing of the green message but I would need processing to continue with the following purple message even though the semantics of `OnError` require the termination of the stream. The green bar at the end represents `OnCompleted` which in this case would essentially mean the closing of the application rather than the successful completion of any one message.

Is there a way to model this kind of processing with Rx?

Comment: Could you provide some example code?

Comment: @MatthewFinlay I added some additional description of the problem. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `T` in `IObservable<T>` to encode your data seems like the correct approach, based on the short problem description that you've provided.  ([The Power of T](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/Rx-The-Power-of-T.aspx))

There can be only one call to `OnError` and then the observable is terminated, per the Rx Grammar, so that's not going to be a problem:

> OnNext* (OnCompleted | OnError)?

See the [Rx Design Guidelines](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219) for details.

However, you can use operators like `Retry` and `Catch` to continue the sequence with a different observable, or the original observable recursively, when an error occurs.

Comment: I found your link on the "Power of T" to be very helpful. It occurred to me that one possible way of modeling my system would be with the "channel" approach that you described. Essentially, I need an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>`. The outer observable would present a stream of observables that would each present a stream of message chunks for a single message. `OnError` events in those streams could be handled correctly and the semantics would be much more in line with the Rx model.

Comment: Nice! Note that nested observables are really a "window" model rather than a "channel" model. "Channel" implies some kind of callback mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function `IObservable<T> ReadChunck(Chunk chunk)` then you can combine them using `Observable.OnErrorResumeNext()`. This will concatenate the chunks when they call `OnError` or `OnCompleted`.

```
IObserable<T> finalStream = Observable.OnErrorResumeNext(
    ReadChunk(chunk1),
    ReadChunk(chunk2),
    ReadChunk(chunck3);
```

Alternatively, you can combine the `ReadChunk`s into an `IEnumerable<IObservable<T>>` which will also work.